# OANDA API Pricing Stream

Tags: json, api

I'm trying to get realtime pricing information for a pair of currency using OANDA's API so I can calculate the difference between my trade entry price and the instrument's current price but I'm not sure why I'm getting a wrong endpoint error. Here's the link I'm using:

```
 https://api-fxpractice.oanda.com/v3/accounts/{{accid}}/pricing/stream?instruments=USD_JPY
```

Can somebody help me with this please? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The endpoint you are using is incorrect.

The correct one is:

https://stream-fxpractice.oanda.com/v3/accounts/$account_id/pricing/stream?instruments=USD_JPY

Replace $account_id with a valid practice account.